# How to make custom stringers for wooden/picket fence?

Tags: fence

I am building a wooden picket fence for my backyard, and have decided to go with a pressure-treated dog ear fence [available here](http://www.lowes.com/pd_156652-77007-73000600_0__?productId=4331592&Ntt=dog+ear+wooden+fence&pl=1&currentURL=%3FNtt%3Ddog%2Bear%2Bwooden%2Bfence&facetInfo=).

The problem is my back yard has a lot of uneven terrain, and so there are several fence sections that I will need to construct myself. Lowes sells individual pickets, but (**very surprisingly**) does not sell the wooden stringers that run horizontally and hold the pickets together.

As you can see in that link, the panels each have 3 rows of stringers that are 1.25" wide, 2.5" tall and 8 feet long. This dimension (1.25" x 2.5") seemed curious to me and didn't ring any bells. I thought that it might be a 1x3, but it turns out 1x3 is actually 0.75" by 2.5". So these stringers are half an inch thicker.

I tried [looking up standard lumber sizes](http://www.bluehorizonfarm.com/repair/lumbersizing.html) and have not found *anything* that is 1.25" x 2.5".

So I ask:

- Do pressure-treated stringers like this exist somewhere? If so, **where?!?**
- If not, **what is the best (and hopefully, cheapest or at least cost-effective!) way to construct stringers with these dimensions?** It has to be exact otherwise my wife will nag and I'll never hear the end of it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few options (ordered by relative ease):

- buy the premade section and cut to fit
- use regular 2x4 (1.5x3.5) material and ignore the size difference
- find a tablesaw and rip stock to the exact size you want

Alternately, you could run the panels full width and fill in any gaps at the bottom with triangular pieces.

Comment: Thanks @Aloysius (+1). I think I was looking for some magical solution, but what you're saying makes perfect sense.

Comment: +1 for the tablesaw, that's the proper solution. If you don't have one, you can rent it.